# How to do level shifting signal in simulink matlab?

Tags: analog, level-shifting, matlab, diode-clamp, simulink

i want to do level shifting signal from -5..5v to 0..10v in simulink.. anyone know how to do that in simulink?
thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use an adder with a constant at the second input.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a bias block that essentially does this.

Or you can you an adder

[image]